# How to share website to certain port

Tags: html, webserver

If I have a folder with html files (index.html, about.html, etc...), how do I share them to something like `localhost:88` then later `xx.xx.xxx.xxx:88`?

I have looked up a lot on the topic but nothing covers how to make a port direct you to your site.

Comment: You need to set up a web server.

Comment: You'll need a host service like IIS or apache. Once you have installed one of these the port setting is trivial.

Comment: which web server you are using?

Comment: You need to configure the web server to bind to those specific ports instead of the standard port 80. How to do this depends on your web server of choice.